# Scala 3 typed type with monad

Tags: scala-3

I have smth like:

```
type RawListResponse[T] = Either[ResponseException[String, circe.Error], List[T]]
type RawOptionResponse[T] = Either[ResponseException[String, circe.Error], Option[T]]
```

which are used in converters:

```
given convList[T]: Conversion[RawListResponse[T], MyListResponse[T]] with

    def apply(
        raw: RawListResponse[T],
    ): MyListResponse[T] = raw.left.map { (respExc: ResponseException[String, circe.Error]) =>
      respExc.getMessage
    }
```

would be nice to merge it into one F[_]. Instead of having converters for Options, Lists etc.

Any ideas ? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the solution:

```
type RawHKResponse[T, F[_]] = Either[RawHKResponse[String, circe.Error], F[T]]
type MyHKResponse[T, F[_]] = Either[String, F[T]]


given convHigherKinded[T, F[_]]: Conversion[RawHKResponse[T, F], MyHKResponse[T, F]] with

def apply(
    raw: RawHKResponse[T, F],
): MyHKResponse[T, F] = raw.left.map { (respExc: ResponseException[String, circe.Error]) =>
  respExc.getMessage
}
```